# jQuery when done is not waiting for it to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery isn't waiting for it to finish with the function before it calls.

```
$.when(saveChanges()).done(showSignInPrompt());
```

I put console.log() inside each of them to see which comes first. and lo and behold, the latter comes first.

Am I using this the wrong way or something?

Here's what savechanges looks like:

```
showSavedNotification_check = 1;

function saveChanges(bypassDeckSave) {
  // bypassDeckSave = undefined - does not bypass
  showSavedNotification_check = 1;
  if(userid != 0) {
    //values in database
    var subjectID = $('.lib_folder_id').val(),
      folderID = $('.lib_subject_id').val();
    if(subjectID == 0 || folderID == 0) { //if database values null, ask for some
      console.log("db deck location not saved, asked for it");
      //values to set to 
      var setFolderID = $('.libDeckLocationModifierDiv .folders li.on').val() + 0,
        setSubjectID = $('.libDeckLocationModifierDiv .subjects li.on').val() + 0;
      if(isNaN(setFolderID) || isNaN(setSubjectID) || setFolderID == 0 || setSubjectID == 0) {
        openDeckLocationDiv();
        showSavedNotification_check = 0;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  var deck_id = $('.deck_id').val();
  if(deck_id == 0) {
    // create a new deck
    createDeckThenSave();
    return;
  }
  if(userid != 0) {
    //values in database
    var subjectID = $('.lib_folder_id').val(),
      folderID = $('.lib_subject_id').val();
    if(subjectID == 0 || folderID == 0) { //if database values null, ask for some
      //values to set to 
      saveDeckLocation();
    }
  }
  // removes empty rows
  $('.editMain li').each(function() {
    var one = $(this).find('.text1').val(),
      two = $(this).find('.text2').val();
    if(one == "" && two == "") {
      //remove this row and remove value from updateSaveArray + add to delete array
      var currentval = $(this).val();
      var rowid = ".row_" + currentval;
      updateSaveArray = jQuery.grep(updateSaveArray, function(value) {
        return value != currentval;
      });
      $(rowid).remove();
      updateDeleteArray[updateDeleteArray.length] = currentval;
    }
  });
  if(bypassDeckSave == undefined) {
    // save deck info to db
    var deckname = $('.editDeckNameInput').val(),
      cardCount = $('.editMain li.mainLi:visible').length,
      deckTermLanguage = $('.selector.one select').val(),
      deckDefinitionLanguage = $('.selector.two select').val(),
      deckThirdBoxLanguage = $('.selector.three select').val(),
      deckDescription = $('.editMoreDeckOptionsDiv textarea').val();
    if($('.editMoreDeckOptionsSelector .onlyme').hasClass("on")) {
      var viewPreferences = 1;
    } else {
      var viewPreferences = 0;
    }
    if($('.editUseThirdboxDiv').hasClass('on')) {
      var thirdbox = 1;
    } else {
      var thirdbox = 2;
    }
    // console.log("deckInfoSave called");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/edit/deckInfoSave.php",
      data: {
        pDeckid: deck_id,
        pDeckname: deckname,
        pCardCount: cardCount,
        pDeckTermLanguage: deckTermLanguage,
        pDeckDefinitionLanguage: deckDefinitionLanguage,
        pDeckThirdBoxLanguage: deckThirdBoxLanguage,
        pThirdbox: thirdbox,
        pDeckDescription: deckDescription,
        pViewPreferences: viewPreferences
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      // console.log(data);
      // decksaved = 1;
    });
  }
  // prepares edited card array
  // gets all needed values and stores in holdSaveCardArray
  var holdSaveCardArray = [];
  for(i = 0; i < updateSaveArray.length; ++i) {
    var currentCard_id = updateSaveArray[i],
      rowidClass = ".row_" + currentCard_id,
      text1val = $(rowidClass + " .text1").val(),
      text2val = $(rowidClass + " .text2").val(),
      text3val = $(rowidClass + " .text3").val();
    cardOrder = $(".editMain li.mainLi:visible").index($(rowidClass)) + 1;
    holdSaveCardArray[holdSaveCardArray.length] = {
      "card_id": currentCard_id,
      "text1val": text1val,
      "text2val": text2val,
      "text3val": text3val,
      "cardOrder": cardOrder
    };
  }
  // console.log(print_r(holdSaveCardArray));
  // delete cards start
  // deletes any card with an id in updateDeleteArray
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/deleteCards.php",
    data: {
      pDeck_id: deck_id,
      pDeleteArray: updateDeleteArray
    }
  }).done(function(msg) {
    // $('.temp').append(msg);
    updateDeleteArray = [];
  });
  // save cards to database
  // loops through each card that had changes made to it
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/saveCardsArray.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      pDeck_id: deck_id,
      pCardArray: holdSaveCardArray
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var temp_id = data[i]["temp_id"], // new id
        card_key = data[i]["card_key"], // old id
        currentClassName = 'row_' + temp_id,
        currentClass = '.row_' + temp_id,
        nextClassName = 'row_' + card_key;
      $(currentClass).val(card_key);
      $(currentClass).removeClass(currentClassName).addClass(nextClassName);
    }
  });
  updateSaveArray = [];
  // update order start  // uses li value
  updateOrderArray = [];
  $('.editMain').find(".mainLi").each(function() {
    var temp = $(this).val();
    updateOrderArray[updateOrderArray.length] = temp;
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/orderCards.php",
    data: {
      pUpdateOrderArray: updateOrderArray
    }
  }).done(function(msg) {
    updateOrder = 0;
  });
  closeLibDLM();
  console.log("closeLibDLM");
  changeSaveStudyButton(1);
} //saveChanges function end
```

The log at the bottom will print after something in the done area.

Comment: Can you show us `saveChanges` implementation as well?

Comment: @drinchev uploaded, sorry it's sort of long.

Comment: Use `.done(showSignInPrompt)` instead of `.done(showSignInPrompt())` - you have to pass a callback *function*! And use `then` instead of `done`.

Comment: From what you've posted, it doesn't actually look like there's any async code in there to begin with. If that's the case, simply `saveChanges(); showSignInPrompt();` would have the same effect.

Comment: `saveChanges` needs to actually **`return`** a promise for anything to work.

Comment: @Taplar sure, but we wouldn't need `$.when` at all if it synchronously returned a value. And you can see from the code in the question that it actually does asynchronous things.

Comment: My bad, I was missreading the scope, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing multiple ajax calls, you will have to change up your logic slightly.  What you will need to do is collect an array of those promises.  Create something like.

```
var promises = [];
```

Every time you do an ajax call, push that ajax promise into that array and return it at the end.  Then your when logic would change slightly.

```
$.when.apply(jQuery, saveChanges()).done(...);
```

apply() will take the array returned and treat it as if you had given each of those promises to when as an argument.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score -1):

`$.when` is used for running promises.

Promise is a function that is running async operation and has internal callback.

In your case you need to modify `saveChanges()` in such a manner that it returns this kind of function.

`$.ajax` is such a function.

So your code should look something like :

```
function saveChanges() { 

   ...

   return $.ajax( .... )

}
```

Then you should do

```
$.when( function() { return saveChanges() } )
 .done( function() { return showSignInPrompt() } )
```

Comment: In this case there is multiple ajax calls, is it possible to combine them all together in `when`? Or do I need to make separate whens for each?

Comment: No, you cannot "run" promises. That's not what `$.when` does. And promises aren't functions either.